# Check duplicate item in object

Tags: javascript

I have a structure like this and I want to check if there are duplicate URL in the array so I can target those and make some conditional statements depending on the Keyword property. Thank you in advance.

```
{
   "prochat": [{
          "Title": "Multiple KB Page",
          "Message": "Hi, Multiple KB Page?",
          "ProblemDescription": "Multiple KB Page",
          "Keyword": "",
          "Template": 1,
          "URL": "www.abcd.com"
        },  
       {
        "Title": "URL 1",
        "Message": "Do you want to Renew?",
        "ProblemDescription": "Message about Installing",
        "Keyword": "Renewals",
        "Template": 1,
        "URL": "www.nba.com"
     },

    {
        "Title": "URL 1",
        "Message": "Do you want to Install?",
        "ProblemDescription": "Message about Installing",
        "Keyword": "Installings",
        "Template": 1,
        "URL": "www.nba.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a condition statement like this

`if (window.location.href.indexOf(data.prochat[i].URL) > -1) { // logic here }`

basically I need to match the url and if it matches i''ll show a button. however there are some duplicate url too so I want if there are duplicates I will just rely on Keyword property if it has the same url.

Comment: I have a condition statement like this                                                            if (window.location.href.indexOf(data.prochat[i].URL) > -1) {  // logic here  } basically I need to match the url and if it matches i''ll show a button. however there are some duplicate url too so I want if there are duplicates I will just rely on Keyword property if it has the same url.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate your data, if the URL is new simply add it to a new array. If it's already in it, handle it as you wish since it is a duplicate.

You can try the following code:

```
var myJSON = {
   "prochat": [{
          "Title": "Multiple KB Page",
          "Message": "Hi, Multiple KB Page?",
          "ProblemDescription": "Multiple KB Page",
          "Keyword": "",
          "Template": 1,
          "URL": "www.abcd.com"
        },  
       {
        "Title": "URL 1",
        "Message": "Do you want to Renew?",
        "ProblemDescription": "Message about Installing",
        "Keyword": "Renewals",
        "Template": 1,
        "URL": "www.nba.com"
     },

    {
        "Title": "URL 1",
        "Message": "Do you want to Install?",
        "ProblemDescription": "Message about Installing",
        "Keyword": "Installings",
        "Template": 1,
        "URL": "www.nba.com"
    }
  ]
};

    var duplicateURLs = [];
    for(var key in myJSON.prochat){
        if(myJSON.prochat.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        if(duplicateURLs.indexOf(myJSON.prochat[key].URL) > 0){
            // URL is duplicate, do stuff
        }
        else{
            duplicateURLs.push(myJSON.prochat[key].URL);
        }
      }
    }
```

You can try it online on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb45rnjm/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var newarray=[];
var object={
   "prochat": [{
          "Title": "Multiple KB Page",
          "Message": "Hi, Multiple KB Page?",
          "ProblemDescription": "Multiple KB Page",
          "Keyword": "",
          "Template": 1,
          "URL": "www.abcd.com"
        },  
       {
        "Title": "URL 1",
        "Message": "Do you want to Renew?",
        "ProblemDescription": "Message about Installing",
        "Keyword": "Renewals",
        "Template": 1,
        "URL": "www.nba.com"
     },

    {
        "Title": "URL 1",
        "Message": "Do you want to Install?",
        "ProblemDescription": "Message about Installing",
        "Keyword": "Installings",
        "Template": 1,
        "URL": "www.nba.com"
    }
  ]
}
console.log(object.prochat.length);
for(var i=0;i<object.prochat.length;i++){
    for(var j=i+1;j<object.prochat.length;j++){
    if(object.prochat[i].URL==object.prochat[j].URL){
    console.log("url matches"+i+j);
    newarray.push(object.projact[i].URL);
  }
}
```